# GCP Vertex AI NLP multiclassification model Api calls from Node js

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've been trying for couple of days to make it calls to a endpoint of a VertexAI multiclassification in my project. But different from python that gives code the code outright for the calls to the API you need to kind read the documentation to get the result. I made it work using `cURL` in the command prompt. But when I try to use in javascript it doesn't seem to work properly. I have an issue with the payload of the AI. I'm using `@google-cloud/aiplatform: 2.6.0` package

```
const cred = require("./credentials.json");
const { PredictionServiceClient } = require("@google-cloud/aiplatform");
const clientOptions = {
    apiEndpoint: "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
    credentials: cred,
};
 async function predict(sentences) {
    const client = new PredictionServiceClient(clientOptions);
    const parent = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}/endpoint/${endpointId}`;
    const result = [];
        await client.rawPredict({
            endpoint: parent,
            httpBody: {
                 instances: {
                     mimeType: "text/plain",
                     content: "Dogs rule",
                 },
            },
        });
    
    return result;
}
```

I did the `httpBody` like this because of sample request using `cURL`:

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/ui/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/endpoints/${ENDPOINT_ID}:predict -d '{
  "instances": {
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "content": "YOUR_TEXT_CONTENT"
  }
}'
```

The error I keep again(Is the same error that I get with `client.predict()`):

```
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 3,
  details: 'Request contains an invalid argument.',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(1) { 'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  }
}
```

The question I have is how to make it work with `client.rawPredict()` or even `client.predict()`.
Because is not really specific how `httpBody` obj should be `rawPredict` or the instances obj for `predict()`

To the request to work as it should